# ESXi onboard SATA passthrough Solaris vm cannot see disks

Tags: vmware-esxi, solaris, sata, passthrough, hardware

Usings an Asus Z8NA-D6, Xeon 5200... I believe they're on the [HCL](http://www.vm-help.com//esx40i/esx40_whitebox_HCL.php).

Attempting something similar to this: http://www.napp-it.org/doc/downloads/all-in-one.pdf

- ESXi 4.1 U1 as hypervisor
- Hypervisor & 1st Guest OS(Solaris Express 11) installed onto h/w RAID 1
- Passthrough onboard SATA to 1st Guest OS
- Create ZFS stripe/mirror array shared via NFS to ESXi

During the VMWare install it can see all the drives attached to onboard SATA.

Have followed [instructions](http://www.servethehome.com/configure-passthrough-vmdirectpath-vmware-esxi-raid-hba-usb-drive/) to enable passthrough - enabled VT/d for CPU and motherboard, assigned the PCI card to the Solaris guest, etc.

The Solaris guest **cannot see any of the drives**, if I run the *Device Driver Utility* it detects both controllers (2 port and 4 port) Intel 82801JI (ICH10 Family). *pci-ide* is the driver. I don't know how to test functionality beyond that. I can't find any trace of disks with *format* or in */dev/dsk*

Not an expert with Solaris, so I am unsure whether this is a Solaris config issue or a VMWare issue. I'd appreciate any expertise someone could offer.

Comment: Device & Driver details tells me that the devfs path for one of the controllers is /pci@0,0/pci15ad,7a0@16/pci-ide@0

Comment: If I run prtconf there are a few instances which say 'driver not attached' - useful?

Comment: Booting directly from the Solaris Express CD and I can see all drives attached to the onboard controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I fixed it:

The SATA Controller needs to be set to AHCI (this is done in the BIOS).

After that was set I was able to see the drives in my virtual machine.

Hopefully this might help someone.